# Load entire json file into single column of BigQuery Table

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to load json file with more then 100 columns into Bigquery. Some of these columns has special character within their name i.e. dollar sign($) and period(.)  Rows/Records content also varies - meaning not all columns may be present in each row/record which is totally acceptable json format.

I have search similar posts

[How to manage/handle schema changes while loading JSON file into BigQuery table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48903222/how-to-manage-handle-schema-changes-while-loading-json-file-into-bigquery-table)

[BigQuery: Create column of JSON datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37660579/bigquery-create-column-of-json-datatype)

which suggest to load the data into single "STRING" column as CSV format first and parse out columns using JSON_EXTRACT() function to target table. Hence I have created a BigQuery table with following schema definition:

[
  {
    "name": "data", 
    "type": "STRING"
  }
    ]

then I have ran following CLI command:

bq load --source_format=CSV test.bq_load_test ./data_file.json ./bq_load_test_schema.json

which result into following error:

**Error Message:
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job : Error
while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the
errors[] collection for more details.
Failure details:
- Error while reading data, error message: Too many values in row
starting at position: 0.**

Here's the data file layout:

```
root
|-- $insert_id: string (nullable = true)
|-- $schema: long (nullable = true)
|-- adid: string (nullable = true)
|-- vendor_attribution_ids: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|-- vendor_event_type: string (nullable = true)
|-- vendor_id: long (nullable = true)
|-- app: long (nullable = true)
|-- city: string (nullable = true)
|-- client_event_time: string (nullable = true)
|-- client_upload_time: string (nullable = true)
|-- country: string (nullable = true)
|-- data: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- first_event: boolean (nullable = true)
|-- device_brand: string (nullable = true)
|-- device_carrier: string (nullable = true)
|-- device_family: string (nullable = true)
|-- device_id: string (nullable = true)
|-- device_manufacturer: string (nullable = true)
|-- device_model: string (nullable = true)
|-- device_type: string (nullable = true)
|-- dma: string (nullable = true)
|-- event_id: long (nullable = true)
|-- event_properties: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- U.vf: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- app.name: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- app.pillar: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- app.version: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- categories: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|    |-- cmfAppId: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.area: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.authenticated: boolean (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.authors: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|    |-- content.cms: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.id: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.keywords.collections: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|    |-- content.keywords.company: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|    |-- content.keywords.location: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|    |-- content.keywords.organization: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|    |-- content.keywords.person: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|    |-- content.keywords.subject: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|    |-- content.keywords.tag: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|    |-- content.media.audiovideo: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.media.contentarea: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.media.duration: long (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.media.episodenumber: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.media.genre: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.media.length: double (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.media.liveondemand: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.media.region: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.media.seasonnumber: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.media.show: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.media.sport: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.media.streamtitle: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.media.type: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.originaltitle: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.pubdate: long (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.publishedtime: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.subsection1: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.subsection2: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.subsection3: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.subsection4: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.tier: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.title: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.type: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.updatedtime: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- content.url: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- custom.DNT: boolean (nullable = true)
|    |-- custom.cookiesenabled: boolean (nullable = true)
|    |-- custom.engine: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- feature.name: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- feature.position: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- lastupdate: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- pubdate: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- referrer.campaign: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- referrer.url: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- syndicate: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- user.interests.explicit.no: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|    |-- user.interests.explicit.yes: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|    |-- user.tier: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- userTier: string (nullable = true)
|-- event_time: string (nullable = true)
|-- event_type: string (nullable = true)
|-- idfa: string (nullable = true)
|-- ip_address: string (nullable = true)
|-- is_attribution_event: boolean (nullable = true)
|-- language: string (nullable = true)
|-- library: string (nullable = true)
|-- location_lat: double (nullable = true)
|-- location_lng: double (nullable = true)
|-- os_name: string (nullable = true)
|-- os_version: string (nullable = true)
|-- paying: string (nullable = true)
|-- platform: string (nullable = true)
|-- processed_time: string (nullable = true)
|-- region: string (nullable = true)
|-- sample_rate: string (nullable = true)
|-- server_received_time: string (nullable = true)
|-- server_upload_time: string (nullable = true)
|-- session_id: long (nullable = true)
|-- start_version: string (nullable = true)
|-- user_creation_time: string (nullable = true)
|-- user_id: string (nullable = true)
|-- user_properties: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- internal.userID: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- internal.userTier: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- experiment.id: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|    |-- experiment.variant: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|    |-- location.news: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- location.radio: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- location.region: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- location.tv: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- location.weather: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- referrer.campaign: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- user.id: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- user.id.internalvisitor: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- user.tier: string (nullable = true)
|-- uuid: string (nullable = true)
|-- version_name: string (nullable = true)
|-- feature_origin: string (nullable = true)
```

Here's the snippet of the data file:

```
{"server_received_time":"2019-01-17 15:00:00.482000","app":161,"device_carrier":null,"$schema":12,"city":"Caro","user_id":null,"uuid":"9018","event_time":"2019-01-17 15:00:00.045000","platform":"Web","os_version":"49","vendor_id":711,"processed_time":"2019-01-17 15:00:00.817195","user_creation_time":"2018-11-01 19:16:34.971000","version_name":null,"ip_address":null,"paying":null,"dma":null,"group_properties":{},"user_properties":{"location.radio":"ca","vendor.userTier":"free","vendor.userID":"a989","user.id":"a989","user.tier":"free","location.region":"ca"},"client_upload_time":"2019-01-17 15:00:00.424000","$insert_id":"e8410","event_type":"LOADED","library":"amp\/4.5.2","vendor_attribution_ids":null,"device_type":"Mac","device_manufacturer":null,"start_version":null,"location_lng":null,"server_upload_time":"2019-01-17 15:00:00.493000","event_id":64,"location_lat":null,"os_name":"Chrome","vendor_event_type":null,"device_brand":null,"groups":{},"event_properties":{"content.authenticated":false,"content.subsection1":"regions","custom.DNT":true,"content.subsection2":"ca","referrer.url":"","content.url":"","content.type":"index","content.title":"","custom.cookiesenabled":true,"app.pillar":"feed","content.area":"news","app.name":"oc"},"data":{},"device_id":"","language":"English","device_model":"Mac","country":"","region":"","is_attribution_event":false,"adid":null,"session_id":15,"device_family":"Mac","sample_rate":null,"idfa":null,"client_event_time":"2019-01-17 14:59:59.987000"}
{"server_received_time":"2019-01-17 15:00:00.913000","app":161,"device_carrier":null,"$schema":12,"city":"Fo","user_id":null,"uuid":"9052","event_time":"2019-01-17 15:00:00.566000","platform":"Web","os_version":"71","vendor_id":797,"processed_time":"2019-01-17 15:00:01.301936","user_creation_time":"2019-01-17 15:00:00.566000","version_name":null,"ip_address":null,"paying":null,"dma":"CO","group_properties":{},"user_properties":{"user.tier":"free"},"client_upload_time":"2019-01-17 15:00:00.157000","$insert_id":"69ae","event_type":"START WEB SESSION","library":"amp\/4.5.2","vendor_attribution_ids":null,"device_type":"Android","device_manufacturer":null,"start_version":null,"location_lng":null,"server_upload_time":"2019-01-17 15:00:00.925000","event_id":1,"location_lat":null,"os_name":"Chrome Mobile","vendor_event_type":null,"device_brand":null,"groups":{},"event_properties":{"content.subsection3":"home","content.subsection2":"archives","content.title":"","content.keywords.subject":["Lifestyle\/Recreation and leisure\/Outdoor recreation\/Boating","Lifestyle\/Relationships\/Couples","General news\/Weather","Oddities"],"content.publishedtime":154687,"app.name":"oc","referrer.url":"","content.subsection1":"archives","content.url":"","content.authenticated":false,"content.keywords.location":["Ot"],"content.originaltitle":"","content.type":"story","content.authors":["Archives"],"app.pillar":"feed","content.area":"news","content.id":"1.49","content.updatedtime":1546878600538,"content.keywords.tag":["24 1","boat house","Ot","Rockcliffe","River","m"],"content.keywords.person":["Ber","Shi","Jea","Jean\u00e9tien"]},"data":{"first_event":true},"device_id":"","language":"English","device_model":"Android","country":"","region":"","is_attribution_event":false,"adid":null,"session_id":15477,"device_family":"Android","sample_rate":null,"idfa":null,"client_event_time":"2019-01-17 14:59:59.810000"}
{"server_received_time":"2019-01-17 15:00:00.913000","app":16,"device_carrier":null,"$schema":12,"city":"","user_id":null,"uuid":"905","event_time":"2019-01-17 15:00:00.574000","platform":"Web","os_version":"71","vendor_id":7973,"processed_time":"2019-01-17 15:00:01.301957","user_creation_time":"2019-01-17 15:00:00.566000","version_name":null,"ip_address":null,"paying":null,"dma":"DCO","group_properties":{},"user_properties":{"user.tier":"free"},"client_upload_time":"2019-01-17 15:00:00.157000","$insert_id":"d045","event_type":"LOADED","library":"am-js\/4.5.2","vendor_attribution_ids":null,"device_type":"Android","device_manufacturer":null,"start_version":null,"location_lng":null,"server_upload_time":"2019-01-17 15:00:00.925000","event_id":2,"location_lat":null,"os_name":"Chrome Mobile","vendor_event_type":null,"device_brand":null,"groups":{},"event_properties":{"content.subsection3":"home","content.subsection2":"archives","content.subsection1":"archives","content.keywords.subject":["Lifestyle\/Recreation and leisure\/Outdoor recreation\/Boating","Lifestyle\/Relationships\/Couples","General news\/Weather","Oddities"],"content.type":"story","content.keywords.location":["Ot"],"app.pillar":"feed","app.name":"oc","content.authenticated":false,"custom.DNT":false,"content.id":"1.4","content.keywords.person":["Ber","Shi","Jea","Je\u00e9tien"],"content.title":"","content.url":"","content.originaltitle":"","custom.cookiesenabled":true,"content.authors":["Archives"],"content.publishedtime":1546878600538,"referrer.url":"","content.area":"news","content.updatedtime":1546878600538,"content.keywords.tag":["24 1","boat house","O","Rockcliffe","River","pr"]},"data":{},"device_id":"","language":"English","device_model":"Android","country":"","region":"","is_attribution_event":false,"adid":null,"session_id":1547737199081,"device_family":"Android","sample_rate":null,"idfa":null,"client_event_time":"2019-01-17 14:59:59.818000"}
```

Any input? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the right [delimiter for CSV file](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#csv-options). Notice that the default value for this flag is `','` and your data has `','`, therefore, every row is interpreted as multiple fields. I tested with your data and this worked for me:

```
bq load --source_format=CSV -F ';' test.bq_load_test ./data_file.json
```

Notice that `';'` worked because the snippet data does not contain `';'`

Comment: Thank you @enle lin for your response. I was able to load the data after specifying field delimiter. I have used '^' as delimiter though.   All the data is loaded successfully into BigQuery without any error and the table count matched the number of rows/records from the file.  However when I verified the data , I have noticed all the child columns under "event_properties" & "user_properties" are nulls.  Here's the sample query:      SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data,'$[user_properties].experiment.id'),
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data,'$[event_properties].app.name') .

Comment: Is it because they contains period(.) within their name?. Please advise.

Comment: just in case if anyone curious about the answer. Please check here - [parsing json child column with special character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54777596/bigquery-parse-json-child-column-with-special-character)